# mod-rewrite for URLs with extra characters after second slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to return `404 error` for all URL with extra characters after second `/` by htaccess.

e.g1:

`http://www.example.com/blah-blah/` NOT Redirect (no extra characters after 2th `/`)

e.g2:

`http://www.example.com/blah-blah/blah-blah` Redirect to 404

e.g3:

`http://www.example.com/blah-blah/blah-blah/` Redirect to 404

e.g4:

`http://www.example.com/blah-blah/blah-blah/blah-blah` Redirect to 404

e.g5:

`http://www.example.com/blah-blah/blah-blah/blah-blah/` Redirect to 404

I tried this but not works with e.g3 & e.g5 (URLs ending with slash):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/.+ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to redirect request only  if there is some characters after second slash, you need to this rewrite rule

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .*/.+ - [R=404,L]
```

PS : when you're using a dash after regexp, it says to pass matches as it to filesystem.

**EDIT** : this pattern /.*/.+ matches with next example, but I forgot RewriteBase directive, so you need to remove first slash in pattern (I edit RewriteRule before)

- /blah-blah/ => Not match
- /blah-blah/blah-blah => Match
- /blah-blah/blah-blah/ => Match
- /blah-blah/blah-blah/blah-blah/ => Match

PS : You can use this tools, to check if your Rewrite works [rewrite-rule-tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: I fixed pattern, this should work now, like I said in my edit, I forgot RewriteBase directives in my test.

Comment: It's weird, Do you have test to rewrite rule tester ? Do you have another RewriteRule to catch /blah-blah/ ?

Comment: Ok, can you post your entire apache conf ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i replaced your code on top of my rules and it works now